# How do I create squared matrix containing doubles?

Tags: c#

```
int arr = new double[][] {
            new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 66},
            new double[] {5, 6, 7, 8, 66},
            new double[] {9, 10, 11, 12, 66},
            new double[] {13, 14, 15, 16, 66},
            new double[] {13, 14, 15, 16, 99}
          }
```

When trying to create the matrix this way I get the following error:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double[][]' to 'int[][]' [c##]

Comment: why are you assigning to `int arr`?

Comment: `double[][]` is obviously not the same as `int`, so that assignment isn't valid. There's no issue here, use either `var arr` or `double[][] arr`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto suggesting `var` to newbie is a crime :)

Comment: @aepot Answering a typo is an even worse crime :) This should be closed, and deleted. There's no good reason for this question.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i answered "matrix", not typo, really. Did you read the answer content? :)

Comment: @aepot Of course I did :) but there's still no good reason for this question. There's no error besides not understanding how the language works, and that's not the kind of questions we accept here, there are plenty of resouces readily available

Answer (score 3):

you used the wrong type in the assignment (int)..

```
 double[][] arr = new double[][] {
            new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 66},
            new double[] {5, 6, 7, 8, 66},
            new double[] {9, 10, 11, 12, 66},
            new double[] {13, 14, 15, 16, 66},
            new double[] {13, 14, 15, 16, 99}
          };
```

will work..